# Installing PHP accelerator on a WampServer running on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, php5, php-extensions

I have installed Symfony 2.3 on a [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) but when I check for configuration warnings I have the following message

```
Install and enable a PHP accelerator like APC
```

I have tried many apc's version but nothing works. I would be glad if someone could give me a working apc or some workaround because I'm stuck.

Here's my configuration :

```
Windows 7 x64
WampServer 2.4
PHP 5.4.12
Apache 2.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is not a valid dll for it. There is a bug related to memprotect (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59506). The best solution is to go for 32bits, unless you want to recompile apc yourself via pecl sources. you will need visual studio compiler.